# CouchDB Map syntax

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have documents in CouchDB (v. 2.1.1) as follows:

```
{
  "xyz": "a",
  "abc": "def"
},
{
  "xyz": "a",
  "ghi": "jkl"
},
{
  "xyz": "a",
  "mno": "pqr"
},
{
  "xyz": "a",
  "stu": "vwx"
},
{
  "xyz": "a",
  "bcd": 1000
}
```

If I run a simple map function, for example:

```
function (doc) {
if (doc.xyz ){
emit(doc.xyz, doc.abc);}}
```

I get:

```
{
  "id": "4c3406a1d92942b4fb10d1314e0061a9",
  "key": "a",
  "value": "def"
},
{
  "id": "4c3406a1d92942b4fb10d1314e006ccf",
  "key": "a",
  "value": null
},
{
  "id": "4c3406a1d92942b4fb10d1314e00787f",
  "key": "a",
  "value": null
},
{
  "id": "4c3406a1d92942b4fb10d1314e00871e",
  "key": "a",
  "value": null
},
{
  "id": "4c3406a1d92942b4fb10d1314e00906a",
  "key": "a",
  "value": null
}
```

I want to try and eliminate the 'null' outputs.

I am looking at having a CouchDB database with many small documents containing small snippets of information rather than having larger documents containing much more information per document.

My question is, is my document design a good one and if so how do I get just what I am looking for rather than rows of 'nulls'. If my storage design is not ideal, what kind of design should I be looking at to simplify the output given my plan to have many small 'docs'.

EDIT:

Having looked at possible answers, I have decided that having numerous small documents as I described in my question is not giving me the kind of benefit I imangined they would.

I was unable to get a satisfactory solution to the map function to get readable answers.

However, I investigated the 'Mango' query system available in recent updates of CouchDB and I was able using these queries to get acceptable output from a database like my supplied one.

This is what I did:

```
curl -X POST http://admin:123@127.0.0.1:5984/ptn/_find -d '{"selector":   {"$or": [{"abc": {"$gt": null}},{"ghi": {"$gt": null}}]},"fields": ["abc","ghi"]}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Un-minified:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "$or": [
      {
        "abc": {
          "$gt": null
        }
      },
      {
        "ghi": {
          "$gt": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ]
}
```

The output:

```
{"docs":[
{"abc":"def"},
{"ghi":"jkl"}
]
.....
```

A concise answer.

Sorting can be done but sorted fields must be indexed. Indexing is in any case advised for larger data sets.

Reference:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html

As my question required a map function, this perhaps cannot be regarded as a valid answer but for me it is an answer. I have tried the 'Mango' query system a little on other databases and it seems to be more useful/powerful than I thought is was although it offers no means of totaling etc.

Comment: `if (doc.xyz && doc.abc)`? As for your question, it both depends on structure of your data model and potential use cases (how often and by whom documents should be created, updated and deleted, etc.)

Comment: Which the result that you are expecting?

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you. What happens if I want >1 variable. I have tried and's and or's but still get nulls. My ultimate purpose is to get eg. 30 or 40 attributes of the key 'a'.

Comment: >1 variable key, you mean? You can parameterize it to some extent, but it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @raina77ow please see my edit.

Comment: @Juanjo Rodriguez please see my edit.